# How to get bitmap from file manager?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I'm going to create attachments in my android application. I need to attach images.
Here is my code:

```
...
attachButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select image"), CHOOSE_IMAGE);
        }
    });
...


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

            Bitmap bitmap = getDecodedImageFromUri(uri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
    }
 }

 private Bitmap getDecodedImageFromUri(Uri uri) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, rect, options);
    options.inSampleSize = getInSampleSize(options, 128, 128);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, rect, options); //HERE IS PROBLEM - bitmap = null.
    return bitmap;
}

private int getInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    int width = options.outWidth;
    int height = options.outHeight;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if(height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        int halfHeight = height / 2;
        int halfWidth = width / 2;

        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight &&
                (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

I add comment where is problem.
So, I did debug, and on this moment:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, rect, options);
```

bitmap equals to null.

What's problem? What I do wrong?

As you can see, these helper methods are from android developer's guide.

**UPDATED**

I need to decode two times, because I need to get options and then get image size to calculate InSampleSize to zip this image.

On second time, options not equals to null - I check it via debug.

But, after second decoding options has outWidth and outHeight as -1. So, it set to default. I don't know what happens on this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem may be because the calling to **decodeStream** twice

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, rect, options); //HERE
options.inSampleSize = getInSampleSize(options, 128, 128);

options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, rect, options); //HERE AGAIN
return bitmap;
```

Comment: setting the stream position back to the start may fix it. Or get a new stream. As the origional one will have been consumed.

Comment: Yeah, I will try to save original stream, and when I will decode it on second time, will use that copy of original. But, I need to use it twice for setting options, because, I also need to crop image and get it less weight (not 2 mb, 200 kb, for example).

Comment: Yes, I get InputStream twice, and it helps me! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try  `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);`

Comment: can you please add some more information to your answer - at least the inital variables for `inputstream` and `options` and make sure to explain why you use `null` as parameter! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, the default constructor of the BitmapFactory.Options may be giving you this troubl:

> [BitmapFactory.Options()
>   Create a default Options object, which if left unchanged will give the same result from the decoder as if null were passed.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html)

And if the options paramter is null (or behaving as null) then the result will be null:

> [The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be decoded, or, if opts is non-null, if opts requested only the size be returned (in opts.outWidth and opts.outHeight)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options))

Try making a better options object or using the method

```
public static Bitmap decodeStream (InputStream is)
```

Answer (score 0):

What If you try this way:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help me, and I don't know why :(